# 3D image (3D array of voxels) filters like skeletonization or HitAndMiss

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

Is there any free library similar to [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) which would allow me to do skeletonization and HitAndMiss on a 3D image (3D array of voxels)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any C# library so I use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) reps. [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji) to do the task.